# How to deploy an Objectdb project with Jboss AS 7?

Tags: jboss7.x, objectdb, wildfly

I'm having troubles to deploy projects that use ObjectDB in Jboss AS 7 WildFly.

for the start I used objectDB tutorial project which originally designed to Glassfish open source edition:

http://www.objectdb.com/tutorial/jpa/ee

but it kept telling me it doesn't find the Provider.

I saw the problems in ObjectDB forums regarding Jboss AS 6 and made this changes:

- added the sentence  java:/DefaultDS to the persistence.xml file.
- used objectdb-jee.jar instead of objectdb.jar

still I got those messages telling me Jboss cannot find the provider.

If someone know how to make Jboss AS 7 work with ObjectDB I will be super glad to know.

Is there anywhere step by step instructions how to do that?

Here is the full stack trace:

04:56:01,160 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
04:56:01,336 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
04:56:01,382 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting
04:56:02,040 INFO  [org.xnio] XNIO Version 3.0.3.GA
04:56:02,040 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
04:56:02,049 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.3.GA
04:56:02,056 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] JBoss Remoting version 3.2.3.GA
04:56:02,075 INFO  [org.jboss.as.logging] JBAS011502: Removing bootstrap log handlers
04:56:02,078 INFO  [org.jboss.as.configadmin] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) JBAS016200: Activating ConfigAdmin Subsystem
04:56:02,079 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
04:56:02,084 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
04:56:02,087 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) JBAS013101: Activating Security Subsystem
04:56:02,094 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) JBAS011940: Activating OSGi Subsystem
04:56:02,112 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
04:56:02,119 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-14) JBAS013100: Current PicketBox version=4.0.7.Final
04:56:02,128 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.9.Final)
04:56:02,181 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
04:56:02,189 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
04:56:02,203 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
04:56:02,249 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.0.2.GA
04:56:02,445 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-8) Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080
04:56:02,525 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-16) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\servers\jboss\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments
04:56:02,526 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS017100: Listening on /127.0.0.1:9999
04:56:02,526 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS017100: Listening on localhost/127.0.0.1:4447
04:56:02,528 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015014: Re-attempting failed deployment Guestbook.war
04:56:02,549 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
04:56:02,604 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-10) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "Guestbook.war"
04:56:02,893 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS011401: Read persistence.xml for GuestbookPU
04:56:02,973 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-13) JNDI bindings for session bean named GuestDao in deployment unit deployment "Guestbook.war" are as follows:

```
java:global/Guestbook/GuestDao!guest.GuestDao
java:app/Guestbook/GuestDao!guest.GuestDao
java:module/GuestDao!guest.GuestDao
java:global/Guestbook/GuestDao
java:app/Guestbook/GuestDao
java:module/GuestDao
```

04:56:03,194 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."Guestbook.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."Guestbook.war".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "Guestbook.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: JBAS011466: PersistenceProvider 'com.objectdb.jpa.Provider' not found
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitDeploymentProcessor.lookupProvider(PersistenceUnitDeploymentProcessor.java:555)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitDeploymentProcessor.deployPersistenceUnit(PersistenceUnitDeploymentProcessor.java:295)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitDeploymentProcessor.addPuService(PersistenceUnitDeploymentProcessor.java:258)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitDeploymentProcessor.handleWarDeployment(PersistenceUnitDeploymentProcessor.java:194)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitDeploymentProcessor.deploy(PersistenceUnitDeploymentProcessor.java:118)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 5 more

04:56:03,204 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "Guestbook.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"Guestbook.war\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"Guestbook.war\".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"Guestbook.war\""}}
04:56:03,224 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment Guestbook.war in 21ms
04:56:03,225 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."Guestbook.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."Guestbook.war".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "Guestbook.war"

04:56:03,227 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"Guestbook.war\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"Guestbook.war\".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"Guestbook.war\""}}}}
10:40:39,789 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015003: Found Guestbook.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called Guestbook.war.dodeploy
10:40:39,855 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "Guestbook.war"
10:40:39,972 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-10) JBAS011401: Read persistence.xml for GuestbookPU
10:40:39,992 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-6) JNDI bindings for session bean named GuestDao in deployment unit deployment "Guestbook.war" are as follows:

```
java:global/Guestbook/GuestDao!guest.GuestDao
java:app/Guestbook/GuestDao!guest.GuestDao
java:module/GuestDao!guest.GuestDao
java:global/Guestbook/GuestDao
java:app/Guestbook/GuestDao
java:module/GuestDao
```

10:40:40,004 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-6) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."Guestbook.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."Guestbook.war".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "Guestbook.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: JBAS011466: PersistenceProvider 'com.objectdb.jpa.Provider' not found
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitDeploymentProcessor.lookupProvider(PersistenceUnitDeploymentProcessor.java:555)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitDeploymentProcessor.deployPersistenceUnit(PersistenceUnitDeploymentProcessor.java:295)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitDeploymentProcessor.addPuService(PersistenceUnitDeploymentProcessor.java:258)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitDeploymentProcessor.handleWarDeployment(PersistenceUnitDeploymentProcessor.java:194)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitDeploymentProcessor.deploy(PersistenceUnitDeploymentProcessor.java:118)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 5 more

10:40:40,010 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "Guestbook.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"Guestbook.war\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"Guestbook.war\".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"Guestbook.war\""}}
10:40:40,014 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-12) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment Guestbook.war in 4ms
10:40:40,015 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."Guestbook.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."Guestbook.war".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "Guestbook.war"

10:40:40,017 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"Guestbook.war\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"Guestbook.war\".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"Guestbook.war\""}}}}

Answer (score 1):

You may have to add the ObjectDB jar to JBoss as a module, as discussed in #8 in [this forum thread](http://www.objectdb.com/database/forum/437).